# How to give permission to a pipeline to access a resource in Azure DevOps using CLI commands?

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli, serviceconnection

I have created an end-to-end CI/CD pipeline in Azure DevOps. I am trying to clone the original repository and create new pipelines using the Azure CLI(v1), using the below command:

`az pipelines create --name {PIPELINE_NAME} --description {PIPELINE_DESCRIPTION} --repository {REPOSITORY_NAME} --branch {BRANCH_NAME} --repository-type {tfsgit} --project {PROJECT_NAME} --organization {ORGANIZATION_NAME} --yml-path {YAML_PATH} --service-connection {SERVICE_CONNECTION_NAME} --subscription {SUBCRIPTION_ID} --skip-first-run {true}`

I am trying to execute the newly created pipeline using the below command:

`az pipelines build queue --branch {BRANCH_NAME} --org {ORGANIZATION_NAME} --project {PROJECT_NAME} --definition-id {PIPELINE_ID} --subscription {SUBCRIPTION_ID}`

The problem is, after executing the above commands, I always need to go to the Azure DevOps portal and manually authorize the pipeline to use the Service Connection. It shows a message like this in the portal `This pipeline needs permission to access a resource before this run can continue`.

I am using this command to log in to the portal `echo {PAT} | az devops login --organization {ORGANIZATION_NAME}`.

How can I avoid this problem of not going to the portal every time to authorize the pipeline to use the service connection? Is there a way I can do this using the CLI? [image]

PS: All the above commands are executed using Python SubProcess.

Answer (score 1):

According to the description, you could check the following steps:

1. Please check the security of the service connection: Project Settings>Pipelines>Service connections name (the service connection you use in the YAML pipeline)>…(In the upper right corner of the service connection page)>Security, then you can check whether there is a YAML pipeline you authorized under Pipeline permissions. You could also try to grant access permission to all pipelines.
2. Check the pipeline [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/policies/permissions?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=In%20your%20project%2C%20go%20to,group%20or%20an%20individual%20user). Project Collection Administrators, Project Administrators, and Build Administrators are given all of the above permissions by default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there a way we can give these permissions using the Azure CLI, instead of going back to the DevOps UI?

Comment: Have you checked if it works when you set the permissions?

Comment: @SaugataPaul  did you get chance to try above

Comment: I too have a similar scenario, where I'm using script files location in another repo, which I referenced in my pipeline yaml. I don't want this permission flout the very first time I run pipeline, want to pre authorise for all pipelines, as my shared scripts is another repo in same team project I don't have to use service connections